# what is double forward slash in removing traling whitespace in vi

Tags: vim, vi

I see the following command in vi:
Delete all trailing whitespace (at the end of each line) with:

```
 :%s/\s\+$//
```

I know

%: current buffer;

s: search and replace;

\s: white space;

+: one or more occurrences;

$: end of line

but what is "//" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` characters are separators.

Between the first and second slashes, you are defining what you're searching for and between the second and third slashes you're defining what you're replacing it with.

`//` at the end just says you're replacing your search text (trailing white space) with nothing.

Comment: And the `//` can be left off if you want to replace the match with nothing and don't need any modifiers. If you do this frequently, omitting them is a handy shortcut.

Comment: @MicahElliott Neat. Never knew about that shortcut, always used the full `sed` command.